# php formatting array results

Tags: php, arrays, format

I have an array like the following. This is the results of a query on one of our servers.

```
Array
(
    [count] => 1
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => mac
                )

            [0] => name
            [staffid] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => 1234
                )

            [1] => staffid
            [school] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => western
                )

            [2] => school
            [count] => 3
            [dn] => cn=mac,cn=staff
        )

)
```

How do I loop through this array and create a new array as follows.

```
Array
(
    [name] => mac
    [staffid] => 1234
    [school] => western
)
```

I've tried a `foreach` loop echoing the key & values, but I'm not sure where to go from there. There will be more results returned as the query is expanded, but original array layout will be the same and the new layout needs to be the same format.

Any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: You have a "count" in each of those sub-arrays. If the count is 2 or above, do you need those values to be returned as arrays?

Comment: As far as I can tell the count in the sub-array will always be 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = array();
foreach($yourArray as $element){
    for($i=0;$i<$element['count']; $i++){
        unset($element[$element[$i]]['count']);
        $result[$element[$i]] = implode(', ', $element[$element[$i]]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to edit the unset line and change it to         `unset ($element[$element[$i]]['count']);` - but now it works great :)

Comment: Ops :) -> I also changed it